# Orange spherical fungus in garden

Tags: fungus

We have a weird orange spherical fungus growing in our garden, any idea what it is and if we need to do anything special to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: They just look like micro toadstools/mushrooms to me. Pull one or two up to see if they have stalks, and whether they have gills beneath the cap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a slime mold (not a fungus) in the genus Lycogala; most likely either L. epidendron or L.terrestre. It is harmless to your garden, feeding on microorganisms and other detritus.